# Is this window frame load bearing?

Tags: walls, windows, structural, replacement

I am looking to replace this old window with a PVC one.
The current window is set in a block basement wall. Down the centre on the exterior it has a stud. I am wondering if this stud provides any structural support as the replacement is just PVC framed.[image: interior]

[image: exterior]

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the block course above the window has horizontal rebar and forms a header.  The floor joists are bearing on this horizontal course of block so if there is no re-inforcement in the block then the window is likely bearing even if it shouldn't be.

In a retrofit you'd typically cut a slot and install a steel lintel to form the header for the window or install a built up dimensional header either with cripples on the sides or bearing on the a ledge of the block wall.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the joists above hint that there is another room there, so those blocks above the window are load-bearing. Meaning there *should* be some re-enforcement there already.

I'd be inclined to use a couple of acro-props/board to support those joists, while hacking away at the plasterboard above the window. If there's a catnic or suchlike, it's job done. If there's nothing, you *could* replace the window to fit well, if there's not much above, but to be prudent, it would be worth fitting a catnic while the old window is out, and access easy, before fitting the new one. Then, remove acros/board and enjoy.

A catnic is a metal structure which spans a gap under brickwork, rather like a lintel. An acro prop is an adjustable strut used to hold up something at a height, fixed between floor and ceiling joist, often with a board between it and the joists above.

Comment: it might be helpful to define what "acro-props/boards" and "catnic or suchlike" are. While they're obviously very familiar to you, they may be regional terms that aren't familiar to others.

Answer (score 0):

The course of block across the top of the window as well as the cells of the blocks along the sides should be filled with concrete and reinforced with rebar.
You may be able to tap the sides and tell if they sound solid.
If so, you can change the window without any other reinforcement.